# Slow process to generate csv of 200k lines Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, csv, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to generate a csv file from a table that has 200k records but the process is very slow so far it lasts 15 minutes and doesn't finish.

If I run only the BULK COLLECT part it processes in 23 seconds but adding the for each of the sources cursor is when the cursor never ends for this case it returns 3 records.

What could be the fastest way to perform this process?

My code:

```
DECLARE
        TYPE v_fbdilayout_rec IS RECORD (
            id_line                                        NUMBER,
            status_code                                    VARCHAR2(100),
            ledger_id                                      VARCHAR2(100),
            effective_date_of_transaction                  VARCHAR2(100),
            journal_source                                 VARCHAR2(100),
            journal_category                               VARCHAR2(100),
            currency_code                                  VARCHAR2(100),
            journal_entry_creation_date                    VARCHAR2(100),
            actual_flag                                    VARCHAR2(100),
            segment1                                       VARCHAR2(100),
            segment2                                       VARCHAR2(100),
            segment3                                       VARCHAR2(100)
        );
        --v_fbdilayout_rec
        TYPE v_fbdilayout_tab IS
            TABLE OF v_fbdilayout_rec;
        v_fbdilayout  v_fbdilayout_tab;
        
        --cursor sources
        CURSOR c_source_types IS
        SELECT DISTINCT
            journal_source source
        FROM
            journals_fbdi_layout
        WHERE
            id_proceso_oic = '1';
                --id_proceso_oic = p_id_proceso_oic;
        
        --variables
        v_csv_line    CLOB;
        g_zipped_blob BLOB;
        v_blob_csv_line BLOB;
    BEGIN
        FOR curr_source IN c_source_types LOOP
            v_csv_line := NULL;
            g_zipped_blob := NULL;
            v_blob_csv_line := NULL;
            --dbms_output.put_line('Source: ' || curr_source.source);
            SELECT
               *
            BULK COLLECT
            INTO v_fbdilayout
            FROM
                journals_fbdi_layout
            WHERE
                journal_source = curr_source.source;
    
            FOR i IN v_fbdilayout.first..v_fbdilayout.last LOOP
                v_csv_line := v_csv_line
                                      ||v_fbdilayout(i).status_code
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).ledger_id
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).effective_date_of_transaction
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).journal_source
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).journal_category
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).currency_code
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).journal_entry_creation_date
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).actual_flag
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).segment1
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).segment2
                                     || ','
                                     || v_fbdilayout(i).segment3
                                     || chr(10);
            END LOOP;
            
            --Conversion
                SELECT
                    clob_to_blob_fn(v_csv_line)
                INTO v_blob_csv_line
                FROM
                    dual;
            
            --Zip process
                as_zip.add1file(g_zipped_blob, 'GlInterface_'
                                               || curr_source.source
                                               || '1'
                                               || '.csv', v_blob_csv_line);
                --v_blob_csv_line
    
                as_zip.finish_zip(g_zipped_blob);
                --Insert
                INSERT INTO int_dat_journals_fbdi (
                    file_name,
                    file_content,
                    id_proceso_oic
                ) VALUES (
                    'FBDI_'
                    || curr_source.source
                    || '_'
                    || '1'
                    || '.zip',
                    g_zipped_blob,
                    '1'
                );
        END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    END;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit faster, if concatenation happen at the select level?

Comment: hi @markalex, how I can do this?

Comment: Instead of `select *` do `journals_fbdi_layout.status_code || ',' || journals_fbdi_layout.ledger_id || ',' ...`. And obviously you'll need to change type of `v_fbdilayout` to `table of varchar(2000)` or something like this.